# Is there any way to monitor every response in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to create a middleware function in express.js. which can monitor every requests and responses. I created a middleware but it can only monitor the requests, not the responses.

```
function middlewareFunc (req,res,next) {
  console.log(req.body , req.params , req.query);
  next();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to monitor from the response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should know that `res` in `function(req, res, next)` is a instance of class `http.ServerResponse`. So it can be listen on `finish` event, please see the link: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    function afterResponse() {
        res.removeListener('finish', afterRequest);
        res.removeListener('close', afterRequest);

        // action after response
    }

    res.on('finish', afterResponse);
    res.on('close', afterResponse);

    // action before request
    // eventually calling `next()`
});

app.use(app.router);
```

`app.use()` and middleware can be used for "before" and a combination of the `close` and `finish` events can be used for "after."

Comment: Was about to write the same. +1

Comment: why do you pass `afterRequest` ?

Answer (score 2):

For that you can write two middlewares

1) Before all request endpoints.

```
//middleware
function middlewareFunEarlier(req,res,next) {
   console.log(req.body , req.params , req.query);
   next();
}

app.use(middlewareFunEarlier);

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
   //do something
   res.end();
});
```

2) After all end points. And you must have to use next() in all endpoints

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
   //do something
   next();
});

app.use(middlewareFunLater);

//middlware

function middlewareFunLater(req, res, next){
   console.log(res);
   res.end();
}
```

It can be work around with existing tools.

Comment: Suggesting to call `next` at every endpoint is a bad idea. Next should only be called if you dont handle the response.

Comment: @Mukesh this is main challenge to not use next() in every endpoint. its basic solution for small scale apps.

Comment: @t.niese calling next at every request is not a good idea, but for this specific requirement, either logging or this approach satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first of all, the reason you are only seeing the requests is because of how middleware works. Everything gets run once in a certain order, and runs only once. When your middleware gets run it is most likely before the response has been created. In order to get the response you would have to make your code run when your controller goes to render or something like that.

Second of all, it seems like basic logging is all you need.(weather it be with a library or just console logging stuff.)

Comment: yes you can assume it as logging module also. but problem is i am not able to monitor every response.